# MySQL min on consecutive rows

Tags: mysql

I have a table with data (ordered by date) like this:

```
   Date    | Country
-----------+---------
2003-01-20 | India
2005-07-14 | France
2005-09-28 | Germany
2006-01-17 | India
2006-10-21 | India
2007-02-08 | France
2008-04-19 | Germany
2010-05-20 | Germany
2012-03-17 | India
2013-05-22 | India
2013-12-31 | India
2014-06-01 | India
```

To get the number of months a person is working in the country he is now, I need to get the least (min) date he reported from the last country he is in. In the example, I need to get 2012-03-17. I tried with group by and self joins, but none work properly. Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Tables are not 'ordered'

Comment: I mean, this is how the data looks like if I run select date,country from table order by date desc

Comment: @Strawberry, true, but he said the data was ordered not the table. ;P

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
select min(date) from table where date > (
select max(date) from table where country!=(
select country FROM table WHERE date= (select max(date) from table)))
```

Comment: Nice and simple. But doesn't work if all records are of same country.

Comment: I think it might work if `date > ...` is changed to `date > IFNULL(..., '1901-01-01')` _assuming that date is not one you expect to find._

Comment: I got it working like this:

`if(((select count(distinct country) from table)=1),(select min(date) from table),(select min(date) from table where date > (
select max(date) from table where country!=(
select country FROM table WHERE date= (select max(date) from table))))` . That means, I added your query inside an if().

Answer (score 1):

Here's one solution.

```
SELECT MIN(other.`Date`)
FROM (SELECT MAX(`Date`) AS mostRecent
      FROM foo) AS mostRecent
JOIN foo
  ON mostRecent.mostRecent = foo.`Date`
JOIN foo AS other
  ON other.Country = foo.Country
WHERE other.`Date` >= COALESCE(
                      (SELECT MAX(`Date`) 
                       FROM foo AS inside 
                       WHERE inside.Country <> foo.Country)
                      ,
                      (SELECT MIN(`Date`)
                       FROM foo AS i2
                       WHERE i2.Country = foo.Country)
                      )
```

Comment: Tried. But unfortunately, this doesn't work if all records are of same country.

Comment: @SunishMenon - Updated the solution to take into consideration when there is only 1 country.  [SQLFiddle demonstrating this solution](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/7f9424/3)

Answer (score 0):

Disregard my earlier answer, I didn't read your question as thoroughly as I should have; this should work, though some people may consider it a borderline abuse of session variables.

First, we must identify the assignments:

```
SELECT @g := @g + IF(@prevCountry <> t.`Country`, 1, 0) AS assignment, t.`Date`, @prevCountry := t.`Country`
FROM theTable AS t
   , (SELECT @g := 0 AS donotreference1, @prevCountry := null AS donotreference2) AS initSV
ORDER BY `Date`
```

Then we need to find the starting date of the last assignment:

```
SELECT a.assignment, MIN(a.`Date`) AS startingDate
FROM ([the query above]) AS a
GROUP BY a.assignment
ORDER BY a.assignment DESC
LIMIT 1
;
```

You can't do the `group by` in the subquery as it messes with the way the session variable is processed; in some cases, I've even seen the need to put the `order by` in a sub-subquery so this

```
theTable AS t
```

may need to become

```
(SELECT `Date`, `Country` FROM theTable ORDER BY `Date`) AS t
```

and the original `ORDER BY` removed.